# Automatically start with capital letter in all Textfield widgets Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

Is it possible to automatically start with capital letter in all Textfield widgets I have in my Flutter app?

Is it possible to configure main or MaterialApp function to make Textfield widgets in the app starts with capital letter when the user start typing?

I cannot configure every Textfield widget I have in the app now, because my app already use hundreds of Textfield widgets everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, set `textCapitalization`  to `TextCapitalization.sentences` as below:

```
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences
```

See more about [TextCapitalization](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextCapitalization.html)

Comment: I cannot configure every Textfield widget I have in the app now, because my app already use hundreds of Textfield widgets everywhere. Is it possible to configure main or MaterialApp function to make Textfield widgets in the app starts with capital letter when the user start typing?

Comment: Well, I had similar use cases multiple times, I used to create a custom widget of text field in which I pass on the label, hint, controller and other dynamic values, and set the common properties like decoration as a static value.
Setting these properties once in the custom widget is more convenient.

Comment: As I wrote "my app already use hundreds of Textfield widgets everywhere" so I cannot create a custom widget of text field now